# Microservices : hitting same microservice multiple time

Tags: microservices

I was running microservices in debug mode but i recognise that my code is running multiple times means one request done his job still the other one is doing same I am new in microservices not able to understand why it is happening? is because of multiple eureka instances or what?how can i avoid it?

Comment: Can you explain a bit over your setup? Are you using a API Gateway? Which kind of services do you have?

Comment: @ghovat : yes, we are using API gateway.We are using SpringBoot microservices. type of services means I don't get it. We are having many microservices which are internally calling each others.

Comment: How do you call them? HTTP request? I assume you use than a HTTP library and  if I got your question right Microservice X tries to Call Microservice Y but Microservice X call Microservice Y 3 instead of 1 time. Is this behavior correct?

Comment: @ghovat : yes, you are right.